# Фоновые задачи. Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, background-task

Есть таск, который подтягивает время из инета(c помощью YORT).

```
    private async Task<CheckRes> GetNetworkTime()
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new Yort.Ntp.NtpClient();
            
            var currentTime = await client.RequestTimeAsync();
            DateTime time = currentTime.NtpTime;
            long millis = new DateTimeOffset(time.AddHours(5)).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
            return new CheckRes(millis, true);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return new CheckRes(0, false);
        }
    }
```

Нужно, чтобы этот таск повторялся каждые 2 часа, даже если юзер закрыл приложение. Возможно такое сделать? Что нужно будет использовать для работы в фоне? Понимаю, что реализация на разных платформах будет разной, и что нужно будет юзать dependency services, но на данный момент интересует только Android. Подскажите, куда копнуть.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61678465/5045688 Реализуйте Foreground Service.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем на андройде дергать NTP, если там время и так синхронизируется из сотовой сети даже если нет инета. А если есть суперкритичные к времени операции, то гораздо надежнее их выполнять на своём сервере. И это гуманнее, чем подъедать батарею телефона своими фоновыми воркерами. Ну и [просто оставлю это здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1253726/373567).