# UdpSocket для конкретного сетевого адаптера

Tags: c#, windows, сокет

Стоит задача организовать приём с постобработкой с одного сетевого адаптера и с последующей передачей через другой сетевой адаптер. 
Протокол: **UDP** 
Реализация: на **C#** для **ОС Windows**
Адреса у сетевых адаптеров разные, но в одной сети.

Как организовать в этом случае приём и передачу?

p.s. Сталкивался с решением такой задачей для Qt - там метод принимал указатель на выбранный адаптер, но для C# в явном виде ничего подобного не встречал.

Comment: [Небольшой пример работы с UDP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1253726/373567). Ваш случай немного проще, если вы делаете что-то типа прокси/MITM атаки. Принятый пакет в один сокет, нужно передавать в другой сокет.

Comment: @aepot Ваш комментарий не даёт ответа на вопрос

Comment: Так это был и не ответ. Ответы публикуются отдельными постами ниже. Добавлю к выше сказанному то, что совершенно все равно, как на уровне логики, так и на уровне кода, сколько у вас адаптеров. Хоть один, хоть несколько. Вы вяжетесь на определенный локальный IP с определенным портом, только и всего. [Еще ссылка почитать](https://metanit.com/sharp/net/5.1.php)