# Как сверить ключ и дату?

Tags: c#

На сервере есть база которая возвращает ключ пользователя
А так же дата когда нужно завершить использование программы по истечению срока.
`30498-09s/cs-01 | 60-Days`
Как мне реализовать проверку по дате чтобы при первом включение программы шёл отсчёт времени?

```
KeyActive.Check() // Тут возвращается ключ который проверяется вместе с системой.
if (KeyActive.Check())
{
  Console.WriteLine("Есть допуск");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Допуска нет");
}
```

Какие есть идеи по реализации?
Реестр? - Записывать дату в реестр и как-то сверять вместе с датой из ссылки?

Comment: `Какие есть идеи по реализации?` - забыть про такую систему раз и на всегда? Вы клиенту даете все данные для того, чтобы эту вашу проверку обойти. Ну запишите вы эту дату куда либо, что мешает взять и поменять ее на 9999 дней? Или у вас программа отправляет на сервер ключ, а сервер в ответ `true`, что мешает сделать "страницу заглушку", которая вернет на любой запрос `true`? Я думаю, вы поняли, что ваша проверка (как я понял лицензии" ерунда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все верно написал @EvgeniyZ, такая система обходится очень легко.

Если кратко, то написать на 100% надежную систему лицензирования невозможно. Ни практически, не теоретически. А если бы это было возможно, то на каждом углу не лежали бы кряки для винды и фотошопа. Только представьте себе, что компании-гиганты имеющие в штате крутых разработчиков, до сих пор ничего не придумали, чтобы защитить свои продукты от взлома и нелегального использования. С этим стоит смириться.

Но то, что решения типа серебряной пули не существует, совершенно не значит, что нельзя написать весьма сильную защиту, которую обойти будет хоть и возможно, но далеко не просто.

Есть несколько советов:

1. При связи с сервером по HTTPS сверяйте его SSL сертификат безопасности со своими локальными данными, чтобы убедиться, что это действительно настоящий ваш сервер. Злоумышленнику будет сложнее подменить сервер своей "заглушкой". Ни в коем случае не используйте HTTP.
2. Системную дату может поменять любой пользователь. Дублируйте проверку даты [запросом на NTP сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1253726/373567), только не опрашивайте NTP сервер часто, скажем не чаще раза в сутки или 1 раз при запуске приложения. Но кстати, смена системной даты может сломать HTTPS, поэтому вряд-ли кто-то будет менять системную дату. Попробуйте локально сменить дату, а потом выйти в интернет. Изучите, как оно работает.
3. Используйте шифрование, чтобы хранить "ключ продукта". Для Windows может хорошо подойти [DPAPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection). Используйте энтропию, данные для которой пусть генерирует сервер по своему собственному алгоритму. Не храните энтропию на клиенте. Это будет похоже на замок с двумя ключами, один из которых у сервера, второй у клиента. Я даю идею, вы можете ее развить. Зашифрованный ключ можете хранить где угодно, хоть в файле, хоть в реестре. А еще данные, зашифрованные с помощью DPAPI, нельзя расшифровать на другом компьютере, что даст полезный эффект защиты ключа от копирования на другой компьютер.
4. Чтобы затруднить взлом через чтение оперативной памяти, изучите, почему пароли нельзя хранить и передавать внутри приложения в переменных типа `string`. Разберётесь - поймете, как избежать. [Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1245131/373567) есть подсказка.
5. Не усложняйте систему защиты. Чем сложнее система - тем больше в ней уязвимостей. Помните: абсолютно надежную систему создать невозможно. Когда создадите прототип, попробуйте его взломать, если не получится - дайте другому разработчику попытаться. Для экономии времени поделитесь исходниками.