# как получить текущее время по часовому поясу пользователя без багоюза?

Tags: c#

у меня стоит условие на текущее время. но! если пользователь поменяет время на компе, то он сможет рушить условие, а мне нужно брать его часовой пояс, выводить в переменную datetime, но как?

Comment: Если вам нужна строгая привязка ко времени, то используйте сервера (NTP), ну или на худой конец парсинг сайта со временем.

Comment: никак, что бы вы не делали, юзер всегда может вас обмануть со своим часовым поясом. Время вы можете [с какого то стороннего сервиса](http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip) считать, а вот узнать часовой пояс пользователя с гарантией нельзя.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1253726/373567 + не привязывайтесь к часовым поясам, используйте везде время в UTC + учтите ситуацию, когда нет интернета и получить время из сети нет возможности.