# Пример реализации клиент-сервера с протоколом IPX на C#

Tags: c#, сокет

везде встречается реализация IPX на С/С++, мне же нужно на C#.
Ни одного рабочего решения пока найти не удалось. Я знаю что в сокетах можно использовать что-то типа `IpxSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Ipx, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Ipx)`, но у меня на этой этой строчке возникает исключение **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: "Адрес несовместим с выбранным протоколом"**

Comment: IPX - устаревная технология, зачем оно вам? Используйте простой UDP.

Comment: Да, я знаю, по этому и нет рабочих примеров, но это учебная задача.. технология устарела, а программа обучения до сих пор её содержит..

Comment: Учебная задача в чём состоит? Данные передать? Вот и передавайте по UDP или TCP. Начиная с Windows Vista протокол IPX не поддерживается.

Comment: Можно даже не сокеты напрямую использовать, а например класс `UdpClient` ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1253726/373567)).

Comment: Учебная задача (одна из трёх в рамках предмета) звучит так: Сделать клиент- сервер на протоколе IPX (цель задачи ознакомление с протоколом IPX/SPX). И есть пример под DOS на Си. Две другие задачи, к слову, это Мастер-Слэйв на ModbusRTU и клиент-сервер на TCP/IP (на сокетах). Я программирую (и на работе и для себя) на C#, и ModbusRTU на com портах и TCP/IP на сокетах  для меня обычные рабочие задачи, которые вопросов не вызывают. А вот как этого динозавра IPX на C# закодить - я не могу разобраться, и заменить его на UDP или TCP по условию задачи не представляется возможным...

Comment: Как бы не очень хочется из-за одной задачи переходить на мало знакомый и совершенно не удобный (после C#) Си. Вот и ищу реализацию на C#.

Comment: То, что начиная с Windows Vista протокол IPX не поддерживается - я пишу под .Net Framework 4, так что хоть на Windows XP можно использовать.

Comment: Пример на Си собирается той же версией компилятора?

Comment: Возможно стоит использовать sockraw и реализовать ipx в софте

Comment: Той же версией компилятора? Боюсь, что не понял Вашего вопроса... Я программирую на C# в Visusl Studio, мне что бы на Си что то сделать нужно либо си-шную IDE искать и ставить, либо рабочую нагрузку C/C++ в Visual Studio устанавливать.

Comment: Про sockraw почитаю, спасибо.

Comment: Было бы интересно узнать, в каком учебном заведении заставляют изучать протокол, который устарел 15 лет назад.

Comment: @aepot, по определённым причинам, в настоящее время, не могу ответить на Ваш вопрос...

Comment: Госструктура чтоли? Тогда это многое объясняет. Так бы и написали, что надо связаться с устройством, которое может только IPX, и есть только XP. Ответ ниже в принципе, вам нужно драйвер на сетевой интерфейс повесить, либо использовать юзермод-реализацию через RAW сокет.

Comment: Нет, не госструктура, действительно просто учебная ВУЗовская задача. Просто были прецеденты, когда студенты, скажем так, в последствии жалели о своих публичных высказываниях в негативном ключе о своём месте обучения. П.С. Ответ ниже изучаю, молча при этом ругаясь, что какая та простая лаба по устаревшей технологии отнимает столько времени и сил.

Answer (score 2):

В первую очередь нужно зайти в центр управления сетями и добавить протокол ipx на интерфейс.

Если драйвера ipx нет, то можно реализовать его в софте. Собрать пакет ipx вручную и передать через sock_raw, IPPROTO_RAW.